# Selecting items from multiple context menus

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

So here is my problem, I have two context menus bound to two buttons, they take the options from db tables.

```
    final Button bButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BeerButton);
                bButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        registerForContextMenu(bButton);
                        openContextMenu(bButton);
                    }
                });

                final Button fButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FireButton);
                fButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        registerForContextMenu(fButton);
                        openContextMenu(fButton);
                    }           
                });
            }

    @Override
         public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu cmenu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo cmenuInfo) 
         {
             super.onCreateContextMenu(cmenu, v, cmenuInfo);
                if(v.getId() == R.id.BeerButton){
                    ContextMenu bMenu = cmenu;
                    bMenu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.beer);
                    bMenu.setHeaderTitle("What's your poison?");   

                    List<bDB> bMenuContainer = bDao.queryBuilder().list();

                    for (bDB item : bMenuContainer) {
                        bMenu.add(item.getName() + " " + item.getVolume() + "l " + "(" + item.getCost() + " Kč)");
                    }
                }
                else if(v.getId() == R.id.FireButton){
                    ContextMenu fMenu = cmenu;
                    fMenu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.fire);
                    fMenu.setHeaderTitle("What do you smoke?");          
                    //blah blah pretty much the same thing
}
         }
```

and now to the onContextItemSelected, could you guide me how to do this part? I just need a kick-off, the rest I will handle, the data will be then written to other table for further statistics.

```
@Override
         public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
         {

         //somebody cast your magic here, PLEASE!

         } 
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
     }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an if for each id you have on your menu. Compare them to `item.getItemId()`

Comment: could you provide a code? I guess an if for each of the options could work, but they are dynamic and there could be lots of them in the end